# automatically set all github secrets to env vars

Tags: github-actions, aws-cdk

So I have a deployment pipeline setup in GitHub actions which really just sets some environment variables and then runs the aws cdk deploy command.

```
- name: deploy backend
  run: |
    cd aws
    npm install
    export STAGE=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
    export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=${{ secrets.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY }}
    export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=${{ secrets.MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID }}
    cdk deploy --all --outputs-file output.json --require-approval never
```

I was trying to figure out a way whereby all environment variables with corresponding names in GitHub Secrets shall be created automatically (meaning, if I need a new secret, I don't have to modify my workflow file).

With the end goal of getting something like this:

```
- name: deploy backend
  run: |
    cd aws
    npm install
    # export all secrets
    cdk deploy --all --outputs-file output.json --require-approval never
```

For some additional context, as this project grows, I don't want to worry about needing to add an export line for each additional environment variable that I add here. Not sure if there is an entirely better approach, native gh features, etc. to use here but curious if anyone else has come across something similar.

Comment: I don't believe there's a short hand for what you want - generally it's bad practice to have all environment variables available everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported natively as of today, but there's a community action on the Marketplace that does this: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/export-all-secrets-to-env-variables

```
- uses: oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action@v1
  with:
    secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
```